# I made a Tic Tac Toe game in python 3 using tkinter, but I don't get any output when I run the code,This is my first time Thank You

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
# Code to add widgets will go here

window.title("Tic Tac Toe Board")
window.configure(bg = "white")

theboard = ['']*10
```

> This is the outline of all the widgets

```
Label1 = tk.Label(window,text ="Player 1 :")
Label1.grid(row=0,column=0)

DisplayMain = tk.Text(master =window,width = 20,height = 2, state = 'disabled')
DisplayMain.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

Entry1 = tk.Entry(master = window)
Entry1.grid(row=1,column=1)

Label2 = tk.Label(window,text ="Player 2 :")
Label2.grid(row=0,column=2)
```

> These are all the functions that I have defined

```
def buttonclicked(button,board,marker,position):
    board[position] = marker
    button['text'] =  marker
    button.configure(state="disabled")
    board[position] = marker

user_input = Entry1.get

def executer():
    global user_input
    user_input = Entry1.get()
```

> I have defined the Buttons here

```
Button1 = tk.Button(window,width = 20,height = 10, text = '', command= lambda: buttonclicked(Button1,theboard,marker,1)) 
Button1.grid(row=2,column=0)

Button2 = tk.Button(window,width = 20,height = 10, text = '', command= lambda: buttonclicked(Button2,theboard,marker,2))
Button2.grid(row=2,column=1)

Button3 = tk.Button(window,width = 20,height = 10, text = '', command= lambda: buttonclicked(Button3,theboard,marker,3))
Button3.grid(row=2,column=2)

Button4 = tk.Button(window,width = 20,height = 10, text = '', command= lambda: buttonclicked(Button4,theboard,marker,4))
Button4.grid(row=3,column=0)

Button5 = tk.Button(window,width = 20,height = 10, text = '', command= lambda: buttonclicked(Button5,theboard,marker,5))
Button5.grid(row=3,column=1)

Button6 = tk.Button(window,width = 20,height = 10, text = '', command= lambda: buttonclicked(Button6,theboard,marker,6))
Button6.grid(row=3,column=2)

Button7 = tk.Button(window,width = 20,height = 10, text = '', command= lambda: buttonclicked(Button7,theboard,marker,7))
Button7.grid(row=4,column=0)

Button8 = tk.Button(window,width = 20,height = 10, text = '', command= lambda: buttonclicked(Button8,theboard,marker,8))
Button8.grid(row=4,column=1)

Button9 = tk.Button(window,width = 20,height = 10, text = '', command= lambda: buttonclicked(Button9,theboard,marker,9))
Button9.grid(row=4,column=2)

Button10 = tk.Button(window,width = 20,height=5, text="Click Me", command = lambda: executer())
Button10.grid(row=5,column=1)
```

> These are the rest of the functions

```
#Function that takes in user input
def player_input():
    '''
    OUTPUT = (player1marker,player2marker)
    '''
    global marker
    marker = str(user_input)
    
    while marker != 'X' and marker != 'O':
        DisplayMain.insert(0.0,'Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe, Choose X or O to start playing')  
        player1 = marker
        player2 = ''
        marker = marker.upper()
        if player1 == 'X':
            player2 = 'O'
        elif player1 == 'O':
            player2 = 'X'
        else:
            pass
        
            continue            
        return (player1,player2) 

#Function that randomly pics who goes first

import random

def choose_first():
    player = random.randint(1,2)
    if player == 1:
        return ("Player 1")
    else:
        return ("Player 2")

#fucntion which checks if a index position on the board is free returns boolean value 

def space_check(board,position):
    return board[position] == ''

def full_board_check(board):
    for i in range(1,10):
        if space_check(board, i):
            return False
            #return true if full
    return True

def win_check(board, mark):
    if   board[1] == mark and board[2] == mark and  board[3]== mark:
        return True
            
    elif board[1] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[7] == mark:
        return True
            
    elif board[1] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[9] == mark:
        return True
        
    elif board[2] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[8]== mark:
        return True
        
    elif board[7] == mark and board[5] == mark and  board[3]==mark:
        return True
    
    elif board[7]== mark  and board[8]== mark and  board[9] == mark:
        return True
  
    elif board[9] == mark and board[6] == mark and board[3] == mark:
        return True
            
    elif board[4] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[6] == mark:
        return True 
             
    else:
        return False

def replay():
    global DisplayMain
    DisplayMain.config(state = 'normal')
    DisplayMain.insert(0.0,"Do you want to play again ? ")
    play_game = str(user_input)
    DisplayMain.config(state = 'disabled')
    return play_game.lower()[0] == 'y'

game_on_ready = True 

while game_on_ready == True:
    
    player1_marker, player2_marker = player_input() 
    
    Label1['text'] = "Player 1 :" + player1_marker
    Label2['text'] = "Player 2 :" + player2_marker
    #Assigning input of players to variables
    
    DisplayMain.insert(0.0,f"Player 1 chooses {player1_marker}")
    DisplayMain.insert(0.0,f"Player 2 chooses {player2_marker}")
    DisplayMain.config(state='disabled')

    #choosing players turn 
    turn = choose_first()
    DisplayMain.config(state='normal')
    DisplayMain.insert(0.0,f'{turn} gets to go first Are you ready to play {turn}  ? Enter Yes or No ')
    DisplayMain.config(state='disabled')
    play_game = str(user_input)
    
    if play_game.lower()[0] == 'y':
        game_on_ready = True
    else:
        game_on_ready = False
```

> This is the working of the game, I think there is a problem with this
> section.As, when I run the rest of the code I don't get any errors

```
    while game_on_ready == True :

        if turn == 'Player 1':

            #Check if won 
            if win_check(theboard,player1_marker) == True:
                DisplayMain.insert(0.0,f"Player 1 ' {player1_marker} ' has won !")
                game_on_ready = False
                
            else:
            #check if tie 
                if full_board_check(theboard) == True:
                    DisplayMain.insert(0.0,"The game is a DRAW")
                    break
                    
                else:
            #switch to player 2 
                    turn = "player 2"
                
        else:
            
            #Check if won 
            if win_check(theboard,player2_marker) == True:
                DisplayMain.insert(0.0,f"Player 2 ' {player2_marker} 'has won !")
                game_on_ready = False
                
            else:
            #check if tie 
                if full_board_check(theboard) == True:
                    DisplayMain.insert(0.0,"The game is a DRAW !")
                    break
                
                    
                else:
            #switch to player 1
                    turn = "Player 1"

    if not replay():
        DisplayMain.insert(0.0,"Thank you for playing ! HOPE YOU HAD FUN ....")
        break       

window.mainloop()
```

**#Please review the code and mention the changes that have to be made.**

Comment: Put `window.mainloop()` above the while loops. It will show the window. For the rest of the game, you need to process button events.

Comment: Thank you so much, now the gui is displayed, can you please expand on what you mean by process button events ?

Comment: The code should not need any input loops. All game progress is triggered by user input events (like button click).

Comment: Okay, thank you so much...